# User Data script to call aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to get some files from S3 on startup in an EC2 instance by using a User Data script and the command

```
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp ...
```

The log tells me that permission was denied and I believe it is due to aws cli not finding any credentials when executing the user data script.

Running the command with sudo after the instance has started works fine.

I have run aws configure both with sudo and without.

I do not want to use cronjob to run something on startup since I am working with an AMI and often need to change the script, therefore it is more convenient for me to change the user data instead of creating a new AMI everytime the script changes.

If possible, I would also like to avoid writing the credentials into the script.

How can I configure awscli in such a way that the credentials are used when running a user data script?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you remove the AWS credentials from the instance/AMI. Your userdata script will be supplied with temporary credentials when needed by the AWS metadata server.

See: [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

- Clear/delete AWS credentials configurations from your instance and create an AMI
- Create a policy that has the minimum privileges to run your script
- Create a IAM role and attach the policy you just created
- Attach the IAM role **when you launch the instance** (very important)
- Have your userdata script call `/usr/bin/aws s3 cp ...` without supplying credentials explicitly or using credentials file

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your EC2 instance to receive a pre-defined **IAM Role** <strike>that has its credentials "baked-in" to the instance</strike> that it fetches upon instantiation, which it turn will allow it to call `aws-cli` commands in your `User Data` script without the need to configure credentials at all.

Here's more info on **IAM Roles for EC2**:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

It's worth noting here that you'll need to attach the appropriate policies to the **IAM Role** that you assign to your instance in order for the `aws-cli` commands to succeed. More information on that can be found here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#working-with-iam-roles

Comment: IAM credentials are never `baked-in` to the instance. They are fetched on demand from the metadata server.

Comment: @helloV Good point. Edited above. Anyone that wanders in here should see helloV's answer for a more succinct, detailed explanation.